# Photosynthesis and its subtopics

Tags: cell-biology, homework, plant-physiology, photosynthesis, cell-membrane

**Which of the following statements about photosynthesis is true?**

a.  Photosynthesis is an energy consuming process

b.  The light-dependent reactions produce the energy-rich compounds that are used up in the light-independent reactions.

c.  The light independent reactions can only occur in night

d.  Photosynthesis and respiration cannot take place together in plants

I think both *c* and *d* are incorrect, but I'm unsure whether *a* or *b* is the correct option.

The reason why I think *a* is correct is that sunlight is used during photosynthesis and *b* because the hydrogen of $NADPH$ produced during light phase is used to combine with $CO_2$ by utilizing ATP (which again was produced in the light phase ) to make $C_6H_{12}O_6$ in the presence of enzyme Rubisco.

---

**Which of the following is true about photosynthesis?**

a.  Rate of photosynthesis is directly proportional to concentration of $CO_2$ in the air.

b.  Photosynthesis takes place only in the visible spectrum of the electromagnetic radiations.

c.  Rate of photosynthesis would be highest under the green light

d.  Structure of leaf has no effect on the rate of photosynthesis

Here I am also stuck between either *a* and *b*.

The reason why I think *a* is correct is that when $CO_2$ concentration increases the rate of photosynthesis also increases until the concentration reaches 0.1 % and it could be *b* because photosynthesis takes place in the presence of sunlight, not any other radiation.

Comment: Perhaps you **didn't read this [meta post](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3393/3340)**.

Comment: @WYISWYG edited ... Now is it ok ?

Comment: Nope. Your title should convey the actual question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG i cant think of more .... can u suggest one please

Comment: First one: (b) because photosynthesis is overall energy producing process. Second one: (b) since graph between rate of photosynthesis & $CO_2$ concentration is not linear and becomes stagnant after threshold concentration.

Comment: Much improved, thank you - this is the sort of thing you need to be doing as standard, all to often we are having to drag this out of you, putting this effort in will give you reward: it will be more likely that someone can help you understand the problem, rather than just giving you facts to memorise. Remember to think about formatting and presentation too, take time to prepare your questions - it often feels like you've written them in a massive panic; just slow down and make sure you're doing it right from the start rather than waiting to be pushed by us :)

Comment: Thanks @rg255 but because i use mobile app so its tough to format

Comment: I would pull all questions of this type. I think they turn the site into a multiple-choice answering service and have no utility for anyone else. I'd urge people to ignore them.

Comment: @David knowledge is knowledge whether it comes in the form of a multiple choice question or a long answer question! Moreover why are you instructing the helpers to stop helping . Thats really rude of you. Everytime someone like you barges in a healthy conversation and/or question  answer sesssion on SE

Comment: @Abcd What you refer to as *knowledge* is memorized facts to answer a quiz. It has little to do with *understanding* biology, which is what this list should be about. I consider it unhealthy to such an extent that I posted a proposal on the Meta list explaining my viewpoint: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/change-homework-policy-to-disallow-multiple-choice-questions-mcqs. I have my own opinion as to who is being rude, but I would merely ask you to think of my remarks as a parallel to "Don't feed the trolls".

Comment: I agree with @David. I'm voting to close because this is the wrong type of format for the site. Perhaps splitting these questions up, and provide questions that ask specifics about photosynthesis would be better. I do appreciate the effort in explaining your thoughts which are reasonable and appear to have reading behind them. This should however be standard practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

B. The net gain of ATP in Photosynthesis is 0, so it cannot be A. C & D are obviously not true.

Second question:
B. D is not true, C is not true (it is actually the opposite- Chloroplasts absorb all BUT green, so only green would be bad). Like another commentator said, the level of CO2 only aids the rate to a point, at which the rise is not great. 
http://www.rsc.org/learn-chemistry/content/filerepository/CMP/00/001/068/Rate%20of%20photosynthesis%20limiting%20factors.pdf